# The Google PageRank Algorithm

Tags: web, machine-learning, pagerank, unsupervised-learning

I am going through the **PageRank algorithm**. In the book *Elements of Statistical Learning* in chapter **Unsupervised Learning** the follwing statement is given:

> The PageRank algorithm considers a webpage to be important if many
>   other webpages point to it.

I understand the algorithm very well. But I don't understand **how does a webpage points to another webpage?**

For example:

Suppose I created a *blog A* (www.iam.com) and you created a *blog B* (www.youare.com)  then how does blog A points to blog B or vice versa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: It's OK sir. I will take care of it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hyperlinks. The C coefficient measures the probability of a user clicking a link instead of writing an URL, so if in a page A the user can click a link to page B, page B gets a little more “important” in the algorithm.

Comment: Sir,thanks for answer. Would you please explain it a little bit more with examples.

Comment: If inside iam.com you can click a link to youare.com, then Iam is pointing to youare